# How to get Display Member of All Combobox columns in dataGridView in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I'm Working on a windows form GUI that has a dataGridView. In dataGridView I've two columns. The first Column Type is a ComboBoxColumn for Insurance id and name and second one is Text box for insurance code number.
ComboBox Column's Datasource is already set and works. 
here is code on form load :

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn Cb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = _clsT.Fill_In_DataTable("SELECT insuranceId, insuranceName FROM insurance", false);
Cb.DataSource = dt;
Cb.Name = "insurance";
Cb.DisplayMember = "insuranceName";
Cb.ValueMember = "insuranceId";
dgv.Columns.Insert(0, Cb); 
dgv.Refresh();
```

after loading form i can fill dgv(DataGridView) Rows From combobox items and at last i want get all row's information with clicking on a button.
here is my code for getting rows data on btn click event

```
if (dgv.Rows.Count > 0)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Rows.Count; i++)
   {
      lst1.Items.Add(dgv.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
      lst2.Items.Add(dgv.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
      //lst3.Items.Add(dgv.Rows.Cell[0] get displayMember.ToString()  ) //what i must to do?

   }
 }
```

ok from here i can get insuranceId and insuranceCodeNumber but how to get displayMembers ?
please help me ... thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
dgv.Rows[i].Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString();
dgv.Rows[i].Cells[1].FormattedValue.ToString();
```